# Setting Checked CheckMarks in a "simple_list_item_multiple_choice"

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm writing an edit window for an SQLite DB row. In it there's an Array line that I'm populating into a "simple_list_item_multiple_choice" ListView. I'd like for the CheckMarks in the view that have been selected previously be re-selected when the list fills.

My question is, is there a way that I can either inflate a ListView to retrieve the TextViews to convert toString() or a way to iterate though the Cursor to get the results so I can whip up a for loop for the - ListView.setItemChecked(i , true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, in case anyone else has this problem

> ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList();
>
> for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
>
> {
>
> String msg = c.getString(1);
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     tempArray.add(msg);
>
> if(i < c.getCount() - 1)
>     {
>         c.moveToNext();
>     }
>
> }
>
> final String[] theGroups = new String[tempArray.size()];
>
> tempArray.toArray(theGroups);